# scipy.stats.hypergeom: Nan

Tags: scipy, statistics

I'm perplexed by scipy.stats.hypergeom. Why doesn't the first expression work?

```
>>> from scipy.stats import hypergeom
>>> hypergeom.pmf(14,6,3,24)
nan
>>> hypergeom.pmf(10,10,10,10)
1.0
```

The docs say:

```
pmf(k, M, n, N) = choose(n, k) * choose(M - n, N - k) / choose(M, N),
    14, 6, 3, 24  choose(3, 14) * choose(3, 10) / choose(6, 24)
```

That value at the bottom should compute, unless I'm looking at choose wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> hypergeom.pmf(14,6,3,24)
nan
```

You can't draw 24 objects from a collection whose total size is 6. The PMF is undefined in that case, so the function returns nan.

Comment: okay, so I was reading choose wrong. I was reading it as choose 6 from 24.